# How to uncheck multiple check boxes at the same time in Selenium WebDriver (Java)

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to uncheck multiple check boxes at the same time in Selenium WebDriver in Java. I tried the suggestions at:

[Selenium checkbox attribute "checked"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187772/selenium-checkbox-attribute-checked)

However, only one check box is unchecked at a time.

I would like to be able to uncheck multiple check boxes at the same time. The check boxes all have different ids.

Thank you for any insights.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure this out in Java. Posting for others.

```
WebElement parent = driver.findElement(By.xpath("<enter parent xpath>"));  
List<WebElement> children = parent.findElements(By.cssSelector("input:checked[type='checkbox']"));  
for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) { children.get(i).click(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WE can use as well using "foreach" clause in jaca example like


Webelement parent = driver.findElement(By.xpath("<enter parent xpath>"));  

List<WebElement> children = parent.findElements(By.cssSelector("input:checked[type='checkbox']"));  

foreach(Webelement we : children)
{
we.click()
}
```