# How to validate the checkbox is selected or not using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, checkbox, webdriver

Selected Checkbox Webelement details:-

```
<label class="container_checkbox">
   <input type="checkbox" class="Control Checkbox" value="on" style="display: inline-block;">
   **<span class="checkmark">
     ::after
   </span>**
</label>
```

Not-Selected Checkbox Webelement details:-

```
<label class="container_checkbox">
   <input type="checkbox" class="Control Checkbox" value="on" style="display: inline-block;">
   **<span class="checkmark"></span>**
</label>
```

To indicate the checkbox is selected the developer is using CSS ::after selector.
How can I check whether the checkbox is selected or not using selenium webdriver.

Comment: Which _Selenium Language Binding Art_ are you using? _Java_ / _Python_ / _C#_ / _NodeJS_ ? Your code trials?

Comment: I am using Selenium with Java

Answer (score 1):

Try this out..

```
private boolean isChecked;
private WebElement e;

isChecked = e.findElement(By.tagName("input")).isSelected();
```

Or you can refer to this solution asked earlier

[[Selenium checkbox attribute "checked"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187772/selenium-checkbox-attribute-checked][1])

Answer (score 1):

To validate if the *checkbox* is selected or not you can use the following solution:

- Using [`isSelected()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#isSelected--) method:

  - *Java*:

    ```
    boolean selection = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@class='container_checkbox']/input[@class='Control Checkbox']")).isSelected();
    ```

Comment: I have already tried with isSelected() method. But unfortunately this method is not working for the above checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are familiar with c# syntax,

```
IWebElement ele = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//label[@class='container_checkbox']/input[@class='Control Checkbox']"));

SelectElement select = new SelectElement(ele);

IList<IWebElement> allSelectedOp = select.AllSelectedOptions;
```

will gives you list of all selected options,
if you want to be specific use below might help you,

```
Boolean IsSelected = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@class='container_checkbox']/input[@class='Control Checkbox']")).isSelected();
```

you can verify Boolean value is True or False